# How to get method from Class name

Tags: python, class

I have a very ugly piece of code which assigns values to a field in a Class object.
Model and field are the string identifiers of the Class and Field values. In this case it is an object of a Table in Peewee ORM but can be any other object with it methods and fields.

Since I want to generalize, the function `savefield` passes the "string name" of the Class and the name of the field. Therefore the code uses the eval() and goes like:

```
   def savefield(id, Model, field, value):
         try:
             instruction = f'{Model}.get_by_id({id})'
             record = eval(instruction)
             instruction = f'{Model}.update(id={id}, {field}="{value}")'
             e = eval(instruction)
         except Exception as e:
             print(str(e))
```

In other words I want to call the savefield function in this way:

```
Class Person:
    self.id = 1 # Autoincrement
    self.name = 'John'
    self.surname = 'Doe'

    def get_by_id(self, id):
        # This will retrieve records from DB and returns object
    
    def update(self, id, key, value):
        ...

savefield(123, "Person", "name", "Erni")
savefield(123, "Person", "surname", "Tron")
```

Please consider the code excerpt above is just an example and may not work... I work with Peewee ORM and the Class Object and methods are very different... it's just to give the idea.

What is the Pythonic way?

SOLVED (thanks to Regis who enlighted me on what was the real problem to obtain the class Object from the class name). Using globals().
the solution is therefore:

```
 def savefield(id, Model, field, value):
             try:
                 objectModel = globals()[Model]
                 record = objectModel.get_by_id(id)
                 setattr(record, field, value)
                 record.save()
             except Exception as e:
                 print(str(e))
```

Comment: Solved (thanks to a lamp @Regis May lighted in my head):

Comment: Dear Peewee readers: please never do this. Ever.

Comment: Dear @coleifer, first of all thank you for developing peewee. Second, is it so ugly as a solution? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. This is because I'm confused by you wanting to save data to a *class* rather than an instance. This does not make too much sense. Typically you would rather want to store a value in an *object* of a *class*. And typically this is what ORMs are all about: Provide you instances of classes in accessing data from a database.

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for:

```py
def savefield(objID:int, modelClass, fieldName:str, value):
      try:
          obj = modelClass.get_by_id(objID)
          setattr(obj, fieldName, value)
          obj.save()
      except Exception as e:
          print(str(e))
```

You than you could invoke this function like this:

```py
savefield(123, Person, "name", "Erni")
```

(BTW: Swallowing exceptions will typically lead to unexpected results.)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but the use case is different. Of course I want to change values in objects but I want to access the object through the Class NAME which is "Person" and not Person . the function will be called savefield(123, "Person", "name", "Erni")  "Person" is string and not ObjecModel. The function will retrieve object with id 123 and change the value to "Erni". The eval(instruction) in my example works. In other  words I want the objectModel from the name of the Class. Is it more clear?

Comment: I know of multiple ways of how to achieve *this*. But it looks like as you already found a way ...

Comment: BTW you should not name variables in uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

python3:

```
type(instance).__name__
```

python2:

```
instance.__class__.__name__
```